# Selenium webdriver in c#-Unable click on hyperlink on frame

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, frame, browser-automation

I am doing automation using selenium Webdriver in c#.So in my application, after clicking on one link, there is frame opened on top of main browser window
So i am able to read text on that frame, in short i can switch to that frame.
Frame having many hyperlink, and i have to click on hyperlink named "**Add/Change Admin Message**". But i uses below code to click on link but it is scrolling down the frame in IE browser so click action is not performed.But its works fine in chrome browser.

Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'"+"Add/Change Admin Message"+"')]")).Click();

I have tried with xpath,cssselector,classname,Id,linktext,partial link text but no luck.
Below is the DOM for that link, please help me .. 
Add/Change Admin Message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to *switch to the frame* where the link is:

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Frame("frame name or id");
```

Then, you can locate the link by *partial link text*:

```
Driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Add/Change Admin Message"));
```

---

With IE it is often something magical you should do, try *clicking the link via javascript*:

```
IWebElement link = Driver.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Add/Change Admin Message"));

IJavaScriptExecutor js = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", link);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ...got exact solution

Comment: why we have used arguments[0] .....can we use arguments[2]...I mean i didn't get significance of arguments[0]...Could you explain in brief please

Comment: @simond there could be multiple parameters passed into the `ExecuteScript()`, we are using `arguments[0]` since we are passing a single argument `link`.